# Proving no matrix of certain rank exists for a specific characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that there exists no matrix of rank $3$ whose characteristic polynomial is $x^7-x^5+x^3$ but I have absolutely no clue where to start. The only thing I know is that we should analyize an arbitary $7 \times 7$ matrix $A$ of rank $3$ (then $\det{A}=0$). I also tried assuming that there exists such a matrix, however I failed to come up with a contradiction. Any suggestions? (Not asking for a solution, just some tips on where to start). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** If a $7\times7$ matrix has rank $3$, its nullity is $4$. Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue. What is its geometric multiplicity?

Comment: 4 as well, correct? But what it gives? I mean, we're not interested in diagonalization (this polynomial can't be factorized over R anyway as far as I can see), so we can't really compare geometric multiplicities with the algebraic ones (if you mean looking for something like $x^4$). Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user207918 The algebraic multiplicity is bounded below by the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: ah, right. The algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue 0 is 3, correct?

Comment: @user207918 No. We don't know what exactly what the algebraic multiplicity of $A$ is, but the algebraic multiplicity $\ge$ geometric multiplicity $=4$. Therefore the characteristic polynomial is at least divisible by $x^4$. Hence it cannot possibly be $x^7-x^5+x^3$, where $x^4$ is not a factor.

Comment: My point was that $x^7-x^5+x^3=x^3(x^4-x^2+1)$, so the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ is $3$, however the geometric multiplicity is $4$ (from our matrix) - which is a contradiction (precisely because of what you said). Isn't it another way of saying the exact same thing? Thanks. (To make it clear - I completely agree with everything you said).

Comment: @user207918 I see. Thanks. Yes, we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: thank you for your patience, sir. Have a good day.